# Sass/Rails caching issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, caching, sass

Lately, I've had an extremely annoying problem with my Sass files in app/assets/stylesheets. Whenever I make changes to the Sass files, I need to kill the local Rails server instance, `rm -rf tmp/cache` and start the server again to see the changes.

I've looked at similar questions on StackOverflow where people suggest that you add `config.assets.cache_store = :null_store` and `config.sass.cache = false` to config/environments/development.rb which I've tried, but they have unfortunately not solved my problem. Only deleting the tmp/cache works in my case, I just don't want to do that every time I make any change, obviously.

I run Ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0] and Rails 3.2.15 on Mac OS X 10.9.

I really hope that any of you can help me to solve this issue.

Kind regards,

Mathias

Comment: Could you post `environments/development.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't have to do this given asset pipeline/rails but you could (as a temporary measure) have a sass watch process running:

```
sass --watch app/assets/stylesheets:public/stylesheets
```

Or similar.